# What is the symbolism of the blue meth?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad

I know it's a plot device, making it Walt's trademark but why blue and not pink(man) or yellow.  One user added, in relation to Marie's love of purple, that purple means widow and mourning in Thailand which is deeply symbolic for her character.
*Breaking Bad* has a lot of colour related symbolism but Walt just says the colour is down to a different chemical process (S1/7).

Was it so they could use My Baby Blue and Crystal Blue Persuasion in the soundtrack?!

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking why the *show's creators* chose the color, yes? Because there is a canon answer in the *plot* itself.

Comment: I'm asking what the symbolism is, if any, of making it blue.

Comment: I was always under the impression that the blue was the result of using pure whatever... and that was actually the case... so it wasn't that production chose the color but that science did.

Comment: @Catija  But pure meth (in the real world) is white, not blue.

Comment: I cannot answer the symbolsm about the color. However, you might find some help in [this answer to anouther questions](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/16378/7757). But I would it say that the soundtrack was definitely **NOT** a reason. The meth was blue when they did not even know **if** they make further seasons, not to mention the plot details.

On the other hand, if they had chosen another color, there would have been other songs as well (e.g., Yellow submarine ;))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To [quote](http://blogs.amctv.com/breaking-bad/2013/10/breaking-bad-creator-vince-gilligan-answers-fan-questions-part-i/) series creator **Vince Gilligan**:

> **We had this instinct that it would be helpful to have something distinctive about Walt’s product. And we figured it should be nice and clear** and not cloudy that a proper product would be.
>
> We thought **yellow would be a terrible choice because it would remind people of urine**, and we figured **green would be an odd color** and **we thought blue was a good choice because it feels clean.**
>
> We called up *(science consultant)* [Dr. Donna](http://www.salon.com/2013/08/22/so_what_if_pure_meth_isnt_really_blue_partner/) with our fingers crossed, asked her if she thought it was possible for this product to come out as blue. She looked into it and said not really, and in fact, if you add a color, chemically speaking it would mean the product is probably less pure and been adulterated. And that worried me when I heard that.
>
> But she said, you know at the end of the day this is a fictional story and I’ll help you get the chemistry as right as I can. Sometimes technical advisors will be very rigid and say it will never work that way, never in a million years, but she was very good that way.

Comment: Though I must say, it feels less clean to me and more like [frozen airplane waste](http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/DSC/uploads/2014/05/130228673382812580493701197_BlueIce.jpg) thanks to the damn Mythbusters.

Answer (score 4):

Walt's meth is said to be the purest of them all, ~99.1% pure. Gale goes on to guarantee Gus a purity of 96 percent for his own product. Walt’s sample was 99 percent pure and “maybe even a touch beyond that."

It's also called as "Blue Sky".  And in [Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_in_Judaism) blue is called as “pavement of sapphire, like the very sky for purity." So it looked to me a homage to Judaism believes.

So blue colors significance is to represent purity.

*Note: I don't have proof for my speculation and it's my believe only.*