# Is there any significance in the major characters of Breaking Bad having colors in their surnames?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad

Walter White (and his family)'s surname is a color.

Jesse Pinkman's surname has a color in it.

Is there any significance in this?

Comment: related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11013/why-is-the-connection-between-hank-and-marie-and-the-colour-purple

Comment: I don't think that's related. The OP there has asked about a character's favorite color, while my question is about the color in the surname.

Comment: It's loosely related. You're lucky - white / pink are referencing Reservoir Dogs, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

[Showbiz cheatsheet](https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/breaking-bad-the-surprising-meaning-behind-walter-whites-last-name.html/) got the answer from creator himself:

> Gilligan says they were looking for some way to indicate that the character is bland. So they decided to give him a bland name. White is a common surname, plus as a color it is the ultimate neutral.
>
> The name stuck with Gilligan because “white is the color of vanilla, of blandness.” However, the show’s creators still wanted a name that would stick with viewers. That’s why they chose Walter as a first name.
>
> Gilligan says he knew Walter White was the right name for the character as soon as he heard it. “‘Walter White’ appealed to me because of the alliterative sound of it and because it’s strangely bland, yet sticks in your head nonetheless,” said Gilligan.

Also from [medium](https://thenetwork-aus.medium.com/how-the-colors-in-breaking-bad-painted-a-story-5501e2942722#:%7E:text=On%20the%20other%20hand%2C%20pink,when%20he%20starts%20cooking%20meth.)

> Vince Gilligan explained that white represented a vanilla, bland version of Walter, and while he initially wore a lot of beige and khaki colors, we see him start wearing green more often, which shows us his evolution as a character. On the other hand, pink is a youthful color and was used as Jesse’s surname to emphasize how young he was during the events of the show.

Even many articles conclude/claim that it's a reference to Reservoir Dogs (No words of god I found to accept or reject those claims)

> The names of Breaking Bad’s lead characters Walter White and Jesse Pinkman appear to be a reference to Mr. White and Mr. Pink, two of the color-coded gangsters featured in Quentin Tarantino’s debut feature Reservoir Dogs. [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/breaking-bad-movie-references/#reservoir-dogs-1992)